# How is this process a solution to this ito SDE and how is the conversion done from Îto to Stratonovitch?

Tags: stochastic-processes, stochastic-differential-equations

I have the following process:

$Y_{t}=\left(W_{t}+\sqrt{Y_{o}}\right)^{2}$

That is the solution of the Îto SDE:

$d Y_{t}=d t+2 \sqrt{Y_{t}} d W_{t}, t \geq 0$

I want to convert this Îto SDE to a Stratonivitch SDE. The solution is:

$d Y_{t}=2 \sqrt{Y_{t}} d W_{t}, t \geq 0$

I am confused about both solutions. I included a screenshot of the course manual.

[image: solution]

The manual says that the SDE becomes:

$d Y_{t}=d t+2\left(w_{t}+\sqrt{Y_{t}}\right) d w_{t}$ that is different than $d Y_{t}=2 \sqrt{Y_{t}} d W_{t}, t \geq 0$

My second question is about the conversion from ito to Stratonovitch. I don't understand how this conversion is done. For me it seems like they just removed the $dt$ term. Could somebody please help me understand the principle behind the conversion? Which steps do I need to take in order to get the conversion right?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Hi, I am pretty sure that it can help you  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stratonovich_integral

Comment: @khosrotash thanks for sharing the link. Before posting this I try to figure it out with the wikipedia page and the already existing post regarding this topic. I have not found anything yet that really helped.